# Confusion with the meaning of current regulation for this context

Tags: current

This is regarding powering an IEPE accelerometer. 
Below shows a general schematic of the IEPE power scheme(taken from a website):

[image]

The site says:

> One of the first considerations, then, that an IEPE accelerometer user
>   must make is whether their data acquisition system can supply
>   sufficient constant current.

What is meant by constant current here? Is the accelerometer sinking that constant current or a regulator pushing a constant current?

Would any power supply with very high max current rating be sufficient or current must be limited?

My confusion here is that what is meant by current regulation here? Is it keeping the current constant all the time at a particular value or limiting the current?

There is another example below which uses something called a current regualting diode.

But these accelerometers have their sensitivity given in mV/g. Yet the value of the decoupling capacitor Co below seems up to the user. Would Co has no effect on the output?

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> What is meant by constant current here? Is the accelerometer sinking
>   that constant current or a regulator pushing a constant current?

Both. PSU is supplying a constant current, that is obviously sink by the transducer.

> Would any power supply with very high max current rating be sufficient
>   or current must be limited?

IMO, the current has to be exact -> current source.

> There is another example below which uses something called a current
>   regualting diode.

It can be anything, if it just outputs the constant current.

> But these accelerometers have their sensitivity given in mV/g. Yet the
>   value of the decoupling capacitor Co below seems up to the user. Would
>   Co has no effect on the output?

Sure it will have. It will act as a high pass filter. If you use specified resistors, then the nominal value of mV/g will be valid at high frequency, while it will attenuate the low frequency.

Answer (score 0):

In this circuit, the current is fed to the crystal and the charge amplifier to supply them, but at the same time, it allows the signal sent back to oscillate.

If you didn't had the current limiting diode, the signal would be fixed at VCC and you wouldn't be able to measure anything.

> My confusion here is that what is meant by current regulation here? Is it keeping the current constant all the time at a particular value or limiting the current?

Both are quite the same thing, it is limiting the current provided from the DC supply and also keeping the current constant all the time, by limiting it.

> Yet the value of the decoupling capacitor Co below seems up to the user.

Yes, as it is used as decoupling and also high-pass filter. Co will have an effect, depending how big is Co, it will filter lower frequencies oscillations.